# Wordpress и написание jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Не смог найти ответ в гугле, поэтому спрашиваю здесь.
Пишу плагин на Wordpress и вместо привычно написание $('#id'), приходится писать jQuery('#id') - так как иначе не работает.

Почему так? можно ли как то исправить. Буду признателен за разъяснения или какую нить ссылку на материал. Спасибо (=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress запускает jQuery в [режиме совместимости](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/), чтобы избежать конфликтов библиотек. Поэтому символ $ по умолчанию запрещён.

В скриптах можно использовать следующую нотацию:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // ваш код с $, например
    // $('#id').click(function() {...});
});
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо)